# gnome-session doesn't start on remote X server

Tags: ubuntu, x11, gnome3

I'm reposting [Gnome Session Doesn't Start on Remote X Server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004167/gnome-session-doesnt-start-on-remote-x-server), here, because I believe it's a `Gnome` question, not just an Ubuntu one.

I have an Ubuntu host, which I reach via `ssh -Y`. The client is my macOS laptop, running XQuartz. I can do `xclock` or other `X` apps from the host and see them on my laptop. What I cannot run is gnome-session, which, as far as I understand, should be the whole thing that comes up when I login to the machine from the local console. DISPLAY is correctly set, but seems to be ignored.

Passing `--display="$DISPLAY"` to gnome-session yields:

```
** (gnome-session-binary:5943): WARNING **: Unknown option --display=localhost:10.0
```

Indeed, my manpage for gnome-session doesn't mention --display, while manpages around Internet do. So, I guess, it was removed at some point, do I still have a way to do it?

I've also discovered that other gnome applications (e.g., gnome-software) have a `--display` option, but they ignore it and the application runs on the console desktop, rather than on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

> I've also discovered that other gnome applications (e.g., gnome-software) have a --display option, but they ignore it and the application runs on the console desktop, rather than on my laptop.

I assume you are running Gnome 3 on the server, too, not only per SSH? I assume it runs as a wayland session. The Gnome apps may use `WAYLAND_DISPLAY` instead of `DISPLAY`. Check `XDG_SESSION_TYPE`. If it is set to `wayland`, Gnome apps will use the wayland display instead of your SSH display. 
Try to run them with `XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11`.

> Indeed, my manpage for gnome-session doesn't mention --display, while manpages around Internet do. So, I guess, it was removed at some point, do I still have a way to do it?

`gnome-session` should regard `DISPLAY`, you don't need `--display`. However, `gnome-shell` has option `--display`.

> What I cannot run is gnome-session

I found that gnome-session and libmutter often have segfaults if not running with native display hardware. Check `dmesg` on your server.

Maybe you can run `env XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11 gnome-session`, but I suspect it will segfault, too. Also, you can try `gnome-shell` instead of `gnome-session`.

I recommend to use another and more lightweight desktop environment for SSH, for example lxde (`lxsession`) or xfce (`startxfce4`), or just a window manager like openbox (`openbox --sm-disable`).

Comment: Thanks, tried XDG_SESSION_TYPE and WAYLAND_DISPLAY, nothing work. I think I'll give up, at least with gnome.